# How to store confidence intervals from stata margins estimation?

Tags: stata, marginal-effects

stata experts,

I have been trying to find a way to store marginal estimations, including the p value and confidence interval.

Below is the code I have. All that I can get is the estimated marginal effect of variable I. Looks like I can't specify "ci" like what we can do for usual regression models. Is there a way to also store and present the other numbers from marginal estimations?

```
probit Y1 X
margin, dydx(X) post
est store m1

probit Y2 X
margins, dydx(X) post
est store m2
esttab m1 m2
esttab m1 m2, ci
```

Another related question is: how do I save marginal estimations for interaction terms? Example code below

```
probit Y2 year month year*month
margins year#month, asbalanced post
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to grab p-values and confidence intervals after a margins command.

```
sysuse auto, clear
probit foreign price trunk 
margin, dydx(price) post 
eststo m1
```

The results from the `margin` command:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       price |   .0000268   .0000159     1.69   0.092    -4.36e-06     .000058
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then the p-value and confidence interval are recoverable from the stored matrices `e(b)` and `e(V)`. To get the p-value, we need the z-score which is the point estimate over the standard error `(e(b)[1,1]/sqrt(e(V)[1,1])`. The rest is calculating the area in the two tails using `normal`.

The confidence interval is the point estimate `e(b)[1,1]` plus the standard error `sqrt(e(V)[1,1])` times the critical value of z `invnormal(0.975)`.

Shown with the output so that you can see the numbers line up:

```
. di "P-value: " normal(-abs(e(b)[1,1]/sqrt(e(V)[1,1])))*2
P-value: .09186065

. di "Upper bound: " e(b)[1,1] + sqrt(e(V)[1,1])*invnormal(0.975)
Upper bound: .00005796

. di "Lower bound: " e(b)[1,1] - sqrt(e(V)[1,1])*invnormal(0.975)
Lower bound: -4.361e-06
```

To put the p-value in a table, for example, you could use `estadd`:

```
estadd scalar pvalue = normal(-abs(e(b)[1,1]/sqrt(e(V)[1,1])))*2
```

And then `esttab`:

```
esttab m1, stats(pvalue, label("P-value"))


. esttab m1, stats(pvalue, label("P-value"))

----------------------------
                      (1)   
                            
----------------------------
price           0.0000268   
                   (1.69)   
----------------------------
P-value            0.0919   
----------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```